# Can't compile Scalatra 2.2.2 with Scala 2.9.1

Tags: scala, scalatra, scalatra-sbt

I'm getting bunch of warnings like these:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.scalatra#scalatra_2.9.1;2.2.2
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/newuser/.ivy2/local/org.scalatra/scalatra_2.9.1/2.2.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
```

And finally I'm getting this exception:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalatra#scalatra_2.9.1;2.2.2: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scalatra#scalatra-scalate_2.9.1;2.2.2: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scalatra#scalatra-specs2_2.9.1;2.2.2: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
    [...]
```

This is how I configure my project:

```
bash-3.2$ g8 scalatra/scalatra-sbt
organization [com.example]:
name [My Scalatra Web App]:
version [0.1.0-SNAPSHOT]:
servlet_name [MyScalatraServlet]:
package [com.example.app]:
scala_version [2.11.1]: 2.9.1
sbt_version [0.13.5]:
scalatra_version [2.3.0]: 2.2.2
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Scala 2.9.2? I think that Scalatra 2.2.2 doesn't go with 2.9.1.

Comment: BTW, according to http://www.scalatra.org/, scalatra 2.2.x should be compatible with scala 2.9.x